# Strange column number " :0 " in VT100 terminal protocol

Tags: terminal, console, serial-port, vt100

I am interpreting some output from a serial port. The output is in [VT100 protocol](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php). VT100 terminal protocol use some control character sequence to set the cursor location on screen. The control sequence looks like this:

> ESC[row;columnH

For example,

> ESC[01;01H means set cursor to row 1, column 1.

But I see the following sequence when column number exceed 2-digit number.

> ESC[10;:0H

Note the extra "**:**" after the semicolon. This control sequence comes after `ESC[10;99H`, which means row 10, column 99.

My understanding is `:0` = `100`. But what if the column number is 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's actually valid or, if it is, it's entirely by accident. The arguments passed to the `CUP` (cursor position) command (and many others involved in screen coordinates) is limited to one or two digits.

In the ASCII table, the digit `9` is followed by `:` so, where `99` would represent `9 * 10 + 9`, `:0` *may* represent `10 * 10 + 0` or `100`:

[image]

Assuming the bug holds up for higher numbers (something I'm not confident of), you're looking for `200`, which would be `20 * 10 + 0` or probably `D0` (`D` being the character ten higher than `:` in the ASCII table).

Comment: Many thanks! This is very informative. And I do agree with your induction. BTW, I take `CUP` as `CUrsor Position`.

Comment: I encountered this phenomena when playing with EDKII. I think this maybe a bug/workaround in its implementation of VT100 to support 3-digit terminal size.

Comment: @smwikipedia, yes, CUP is indeed the short form code for cursor position, updated answer to make clear.

Answer (score 1):

No, the relevant standards do not specify that the number of digits is limited to **two**, for instance because VT100s can address 24 rows by 132 columns.

Leading zeroes in the parameters are ignored.  Likely, OP is reporting a problem (from some unmentioned program) which uses only two digits.  That is not related to the terminal itself (except perhaps in the context of a bug report directed to a terminal emulator's developers).

The [resize](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program *assumes* that one's terminal is no larger than 999 by 999 to position the cursor to "past" the lower-right corner of the screen.  For those individuals who do not rely upon multiple pixels to discern characters, xterm does use a font called "Unreadable", which could result in larger screens.

By the way, the source given in the question is not very good, although not the worst -- refer to [vt100.net](http://vt100.net/) and [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm).